# In which book can I find the Rhythm Blade dagger?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, product-identification

I am looking into buying a Rhythm Blade dagger for my warlock to use in his off-hand. [I have found this weapon online](https://just-the-tip.obsidianportal.com/items/rhythm-blade-dagger-1) but I can't seem to find it in any of the 4e books.

So my question is: **in which rule book is the Rhythm Blade featured?**

Answer (score 5):

It is in the Adventurer's Vault 2 page 97.

In the future you can use the [Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/database.aspx), even without a DDI Subscription. You can't get the text of the item (or feat or whatever you are looking up) but it will tell you the book it came in.